# How to deal with the limited Linq support of OData (Open Data Protocol)

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, odata, wcf-data-services

I have a software, which uses a lot of Linq-to-SQL. Recently, I want to migrate to OData / WCF Data Service architecture. But I met too many problems in the Linq support of OData - it is so limited. I have to modify most of my Linq statements and test them thoroughly again.

I am wondering whether there is a system way to solve such a problem instead of my manual work. For example, by an external package.

BTW, now I have no confidence to use OData as a kind of architecture.

You are appreciated to share your ideas.

Thank you in advance,

Ying

Comment: Can you give us a concrete exmample of a statement that worked in Linq-to-SQL and that doesn't work in Linq-to-OData ? What limitations is it you're talking about? Please provide more and more substantial facts.

Comment: One example is here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247051/how-to-use-selectmany-with-dataservicequery

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look more into WCF (without the 'Data' part) Services which can be exposed through a very wide variety of end points [REST / SOAP endpoints for a WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186631/rest-soap-endpoints-for-a-wcf-service). WCF Data Services are more specific to the single goal of exposing an Entity Data Model via OData which is not very ideal for direct back-end communication.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to use a WCF service that takes a serialized LINQ expression

http://interlinq.codeplex.com/